# Convert mongoengine queryset to a json file

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-queryset, mongoengine

How do I dump the data in a queryset of Mongo documents to a .json file using python?

I've tried to use django serializer, but didn't work as the fields are not accessed in django the same way as they are accessed in mongo.

```
for model in models:
    json_serializer.serialize(model.objects.all(), indent=2, stream=output_file_mongo)
```

I also tried to use python JSON encode/decoder,

```
import json
for model in mongo_models:
    output_file_mongo.write(json.dumps(model.objects.all()))
```

I get an exception

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [<MongoModelA: MongoModelA object>] is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2):

The django serializer does not know how to handle mongoengine objects, You'll most likely have to write your own json encoder to map them to a simple dictionary:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode_object(self, obj):
        return { 'id':unicode(obj.id), 'other_property': obj.other_property }

    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, '__iter__'):
            return [ self.encode_object(x) for x in obj ]
        else:
            return self.encode_object(obj)
```

then call it like so:

```
import json
import MyEncoder

json_string = json.dumps(model.objects.all(), cls=MyEncoder)
```

Comment: One path to getting this working is to implement a to_dict(self): method on each of your models that outputs a dictionary. Then  You can use return obj.to_dict() in the encode_object method above. This still feels quite messy to me though.